# jquery plugin function overriding execute function many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I created a small jQuery plugin that shows and hides a div when the user clicks on the button `.show` and the button `.hide`, respectively. I want to pass a function as a plugin option to do some specific processing for `onhide`. But the `onhide` function executes as many times as the show and hide buttons are clicked.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ka9gw09t/9/).

When you click show/hide buttons more then once then the alert will show the same number of times.

I think it should alert only once for the hide button.

```
$.fn.showhide = function(options){ 

    var popup = this;
          defaultOptions = {
                 onHide : function() { },
           onShow : function() { }
         };
      var Options = $.extend({},defaultOptions, options); 
          this.each(function() {         
       $(this).on('click',function(e){ 
         var id = $(this).data('id');
         $('#'+id).show();
         $('.hide').on('click',function(){
           var id = $(this).data('id');
           $('#'+id).hide();
           if (Options.onHide.call() === false) {
                    return;
              }

         });

          });
      });
}

$('.show').showhide({
 onHide :function() {
  alert('hide');
 }

}
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're implementing your onHide method inside a loop.

Move this bit:

```
$('.hide').on('click',function(){
       var id = $(this).data('id');
       $('#'+id).hide();
       if (Options.onHide.call() === false) {
                return;
          }

     });
```

to right before your closing bracket of your method and everything works fine!

Edit: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ka9gw09t/10/

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
$('.hide').on('click',function(){
```

To

```
$('.hide').one('click',function(){
```

**Explanation:**

With your code, each time the user clicks on `.show` you attach **one more** delegation `.click` to the button. `one` will do it just once.

```js
$.fn.showhide = function(options){ 

  var popup = this;
  defaultOptions = {
    onHide : function() { },
    onShow : function() { }
  };
  var Options = $.extend({},defaultOptions, options); 
  this.each(function() {    
    $(this).on('click',function(e){ 
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $('#'+id).show();
      $('.hide').unbind('click').one('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#'+id).hide();
        if (Options.onHide.call() === false) {
          return;
        }

      });

    });
  });
};

$('.show').showhide({
  onHide :function() {
    alert('hide');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show" data-id="123">
Show 
</button>
<button class="hide" data-id="123">
 Hide
</button>
<div class="showhide" id="123" style="display:none;">
This is div with id 123
</div>
```

**Update**

I was added `unbind('click')` before the `one` to unbind the older listeners.

Comment: This has the same problem! When you click three times on show, you have to click three times on ok-button! Try my solution...

Comment: Which is practically the same as my solution! :P

Comment: The result, not the way. People can learn different things from different solutions.. (`unbind`, `one` for example or better understanding the logic of jQuery plugin)..